# Clojure: CreateProcess Error, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: command-line, clojure, java-io

I'm trying to run a Windows command from a `Clojure` program. I am testing it with a small echo statement:

```
(:require [clojure.java.shell :as sh])

(defn testcal [cob]
  (let [cmd (str "echo hi" )
        result (sh/sh cmd)]))
```

Its throwing me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo hi": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

My java path looks good and checked everything. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

in windows environment, instead of

```
(sh/sh "echo hi")
```

try

```
(sh/sh "cmd" "/C" "echo hi")
```

the answer of why "cmd" "/C" is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031412/1393248

Comment: Find more info on "cmd" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd The "/C" flag tells Windows to "[Carry] out the command specified by string and then [stop]."